# Kentico localization in ascx transformation IF statment

Tags: asp.net, kentico

I felt it was easier to start a new thread here. In a previous thread ([initial post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35435529/kentico-repeater-html-properties-showing-with-selected-transformation/35436444#35436444)) I was looking at dynamically adding a the open and close table tags in a repeater. As i'm working through the build in French, i'm struggling with using resource strings. Here's the code snippet:

```html
<%# IsFirst() ? "<table class='sortable col-3'><thead><tr><th class=''>Date</th><th class='sorter-false'>Subject</th><th class='sorter-false'>From</th></tr></thead><tbody>" : "" %>
```

I want to replace the string 'Subject' with a resource key. I've tried a macro approach, and concatenation of the c#, but i'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

The resource string macro is {$ the.resource.string.code $}, so you add a localization string in the "Localize" module in Kentico, and use the macro above to place it.

If this is in an ASCX transformation, you may need to either use the CMS:LocalizedString control, or use a Literal control and then use the CMS.Helpers.ResHelper.GetString("stringKey");

https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Working+with+resource+strings

Comment: it is an ASCX transformation, but with a single line If statement, i was getting some errors with CMS.Helper. I've rewritten the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the if statement to this. So far so good.

```html
<%
 if (IsFirst()){
 %>
<table class="sortable col-3">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="">Date</th>
<th class='sorter-false'><%# CMS.Helpers.ResHelper.GetString("kff.CEODirect-FormLabel--Subject") %></th>
<th class='sorter-false'>From</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<%
 }

%>
```

Comment: Why don't you want use content before/after to wrap you repeater with TABLE tags?

Comment: When i used the before/after, the HTML would still display for the detail page, which is done through another transformation

Answer (score 0):

<%# Localize("kff.CEODirect-FormLabel--Subject") %>

I believe that will work, assuming that is your resource string key.

Comment: How would i concatenate that in a single line IF statement? That's what i couldn't get to work, which is why a reformatted the code.

Comment: <%# IsFirst() ? "<table class='sortable col-3'><thead><tr><th class=''>Date</th><th class='sorter-false'>" + Localize("kff.CEODirect-FormLabel--Subject") +"</th><th class='sorter-false'>From</th></tr></thead><tbody>" : "" %>